# Overloading Delete , in specific programs

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Overloading delete is explained in many earlier posts. However , I have a specific doubt that I  would like to describe below.

We have a toolchain which primarily supports C. However there are few cpp libraries as well which allows us to have a certain amount of cpp support.

[[image: The problem Statement]]

As the picture suggests, we have a main program on which we have a fair amount of control. The library is given by the chip vendor, which we need to integrate with my hardware. We have APIs given by the processor company which we need to use. 
The main reason why we need to use our APIs is that the toolchain does not recognize operator new and delete. However, file `<new>` exists in the c++ section of the tool-chain and works . But, the tool-chain provider says that they cannot guarantee the validity of such memory allocation. 
I am facing an issue with regard to Bad Value Address, when we call a pure virtual function using the object created by the library.
The hardware guys say that we need to use their API which deal with memory allocation and not `"new"` and `"delete"` .
We are able to overload new successfully like by having a `mynew.cc` where we define new as.

```
 void* operator new( unsigned int size, const char *f, int line) 
   {
    printf("the file :%s\n", f);
    printf("the line: %d\n", line);
    //if(0 == size)
    //  return 0;
    void *ret = my_api_Malloc(size);
    printf("the ret: %p\n", ret);
    return ret;
  }
```

I have declared this in a `mynew.h` file which I include in my main functions.
I have read that we cannot overload global delete.

I have defined delete in my `"mynew.cc"` file as this

```
void operator delete(void * p)
{
    printf("the file :%s\n", __FILE__);
    printf("the line: %d\n", __LINE__);
    my_api_Free(p);  
};
```

We are able to use the `new operator` successfully in the main program, i.e. when we use,
     `myclass * obj = new myclass`,

The overloaded new is replaced. However when we do `delete obj` nothing really happens.

In case we have to use `delete` we need to define delete as something like

```
#define delete (x) (operator delete(x, __FILE__, __LINE__))
```

in our `mynew.h`
and in the program we have to call `delete(obj)` , which we cannot do as the callback functions cannot be replaced with our code changes.

Please let me know what could be done so that we can use delete successfully.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to explain **why** you need to have your own heap allocation & deallocation  !

Comment: I still don't understand (even after your edit) why you need your own heap allocation. You probably should discuss with your proprietary library vendor support

Comment: well, we had issues with the vtable, when we used pure virtual functions. the tool chain provider said that its vtable issue and thats why your program is crashing during run time .( compilation was successful). He asked us to modify our programs with their memory allocation and few other issues. replacing new and delete was one such of them. the toolchain provider is not helping and library vendor blames the toolchain.

Comment: What is the toolchain? If it contains [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you could compile yourself a fresher version of it

Answer (score 2):

You're simply implementing the wrong `operator new`. Since their code isn't using macro's for `new/delete`, you should provide `void* operator new(std::size_t)`.

You indeed cannot *overload* `operator delete(void*)` but that's terminology. You *replace* it.

Answer (score 0):

If the proprietary library was compiled (by its vendor) in a context where `::operator new` was *inlined* you are out of luck.

But you might check that using `nm -D` ...

Otherwise, I would suggest you to **override** (*not* "overload") the implementation's

```
 ::operator new(std::size_t)
 ::operator delete(void*)
```

etc...

(like [MSalters's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34763337/841108)). It cannot be a macro `#define new` since the proprietary library is *calling* some `::operator new` function (not macro, which are expanded at compile time).

BTW, heap management is a *whole program* feature. Unless your code and the proprietary library code was designed to accept custom allocators, you cannot realistically have several allocators in your program.

I would suggest to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) when possible and also compile with a recent GCC with `g++ -Wall -g -fsanitize=address` (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) about `-fsanitize`)... If on Linux you could use `LD_PRELOAD` tricks. It looks like you have some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), like [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. Will carry out these steps and check the issues.